# How to work with different file formats in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How to perform various actions with the file, depending on its format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Do-conditional-processing

You could also check `file.extension` (see [sanitized_file.rb](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb))